# How to refer to a layout in java class

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

For example in the onCreate method in the java class, in order to find the element in the layout you type

```
        txtViewRed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewRed);
```

I want to change the layout's background colour programmatically. How to refer to the layout in order to make changes?

i.e.

```
myLayout = .....?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume this is your XML layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/myRelLayout"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I have named the Relative layout as myRelLayout

Then I can refer it from the Activity which uses this layout by using following code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelLayout);

}
```

Then you can change the background color using following code

```
layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setBackgroundColor` method in your instance you've received with `findViewById`.

```
txtViewRed.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use setBackgroundColor() in your java class.this method use for layout,textview ,imageview etc. background.

```
YourLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
```